# Issue with loading SublimeREPL in Sublime Text 3 and Ipython shell

Tags: python, ipython, sublimetext3, pyzmq, sublimerepl

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while, but I have not been able to resolve it. I use SublimeREPL with Sublime Text 3. Whenever I try and launch the Ipython shell from SublimeREPL, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py",  line 51, in <module>
  embedded_shell = ZMQTerminalIPythonApp(config=cfg, user_ns={})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 150, in __init__
  super(BaseIPythonApplication, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 166, in __init__
  SingletonConfigurable.__init__(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 84, in __init__
  self.config = config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py", line 307, in __set__
  obj._notify_trait(self.name, old_value, new_value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py", line 458, in _notify_trait
  c(name, old_value, new_value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 176, in _config_changed
  self.log.debug('Config changed:')
AttributeError: 'ZMQTerminalIPythonApp' object has no attribute 'log'

***Repl Closed***
```

The issue seems to be with this ZMGTerminalIPythonApp object in the application.py module. Ipython works just fine when I load it from the command line.

UPDATE: So I also tried to run the ipy_repl.py file directly from the command line. I was expecting it to fail, but it actually worked just fine. I did not get the error above. So it is not clear why when invoking SublimeREPL from ST3 I get the above error but when I invoke the SublimeREPL ipython shell from the command line, it all works fine.

Has anyone else been able to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have [`pyzmq`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzmq/14.0.1) installed?

Comment: Yep, I have pyzmq installed and everything. I use ipython too, so pyzmq was a requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured out the problem. It all had to do with my $PATH variable. I use the Anaconda package from Continuum.io for scientific python--great package btw. So Anaconda will update the $PATH variable so that its version of the python binaries comes first in the $PATH and hence is the one that `pip` acts against. I knew that Ipython did this with Anaconda, but not the `python` too. So when I was updating pyzmq with `pip`, that was updating the Anaconda distribution instead of the normal locally installed python install in `/usr/bin/ ...`

Interestingly, SublimeREPL was trying to invoke the REPL against the python install in `/usr/bin/...` instead of just following the normal $PATH variable reference to the Anaconda distribution. I am still not sure how that happened?

So anyway, when I used the `easy_install` package installer to upgrade `pyzmq` instead of `pip`, then this updated the python install in `/usr/bin/...` instead of the Anaconda version. That resolved the problem.

So now SublimeREPL is working.